# When a polynomial belongs to a monomial ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $I$ be a monomial ideal in $R=k[x_1,...,x_n]$ and let $f$ in $R$. If $f$ is in $I$, then $f$ is $k$-linear combination of the monomials in $I$.

Could anyone prove this?

For example, if $R=\Bbb Z[x,y,z]$, and $f= 3x^5 + 7xyz$. I could write $f$ as 
$f=3(x^5)(yz)^0 + 7xyz$. Is this a form of $k$-linear combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I \lhd R$, and $R$ is Noetherian (by Hilbert's Basis Theorem), so all of its ideals are finitely generated over $R$.  This implies that  $I=\langle m_1,m_2,...,m_k \rangle$, and since I is a monomial ideal the $m_i$ can be taken to be monomials in the variables $x_1,...,x_n$.

Now, $f\in I$ means that $f=q_1m_1+ \cdot \cdot \cdot+q_km_k$ where the $q_i$ are polynomials in $R$.  We need to show that we can in fact write $f$ as a linear combination of monomials in $I$ with coefficients in $k$.

If we distribute the monomials $m_i$ through the quotients $q_i$ we get $f$ expanded as a $k$-linear combination of monomials.  Each of these monomials has one of the $m_i$ as a factor (we distributed the $m_i$ through the terms of the $q_i$), so is in fact a monomial in $I$.  Then we have that $f$ is a $k$-linear combination of monomials in $I$.

Comment: The second chunk above is the main point.  Ideals are closed under multiplication in the ring, so here being in an ideal of our polynomial ring will give only polynomial coefficients.  We want to show that we can actually write elements of the ideal as a sum of monomials in the ideal with scalar coefficients.

Comment: thanks. but, i do not understand the part "we distribute the monomials mi through the quotients qi".

Comment: you know that you have some polynomial coefficients q_i on the monomials m_i, so these q_i may have several terms.  For example we could have q_1 = 2.x^2.y.z^3+2.x+3.y^2 and m_1 = x^2.y.  Then I mean distribute the monomial through the sum as usual to get a sum of monomials, and since each of this expanded out sum has the m_i as factors it's a sum of elements in I so is itself in I.