# The ideal $(x^5,y^6,xy)$ cannot be generated by two elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, monomial-ideals

Is there any nice way to show an ideal $(x^5,y^6,xy)\subset F[x,y]$ where $F[x,y]$ is a polynomial ring with two variable over a field $F$ cannot be generated by two elements? I.e., there is no $f(x,y),g(x,y)\in F[x,y]$ such that $(f(x,y),g(x,y)) = (x^5,y^6,xy)$.

Edit: Nice way means showing not by case by case argument.

Comment: This should be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251419

Comment: @user26857 I don't understand the point of the link. Question in that post is an ideal of the form $\langle x^n,x^{n-1}y,...,x^{1}y^{n-1},y^n\rangle$. In particular, degree are the same for each element whereas my example is not.

Comment: Please avoid "do my homework for me"-style questions. For example, here providing a case-by-case argument would be a nice addition! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I=(x^5,y^6,xy)$ and $\mathfrak m=(x,y)$.

Suppose that $I$ is generated by two elements, say $f,g$. Then the $F$-vector space $I/\mathfrak mI$ is generated by (the residue classes of) $f,g$ (why?). It follows that $\dim_FI/\mathfrak mI\le2$. In particular, (the residue classes of) $x^5,y^6,xy$ are linearly dependent over $F$, that is, there exist $a,b,c\in F$ not all zero such that $ax^5+by^6+cxy\in\mathfrak mI$. Since $\mathfrak mI$ is a monomial ideal we get that at least one of the monomials $x^5,y^6,xy$ belong to $\mathfrak mI$. It follows that at least one of the monomials $x^5,y^6,xy$ is divisible by one of the monomials which generate $\mathfrak mI$, a contradiction.

Comment: Why 'since $\mathfrak{m}I$ is monomial ideal we get that at least one of the monomials $x^5,y^6,xy$ belong to $\mathfrak{m}I$'?

Comment: A polynomial f belongs to a monomial ideal J iff all the monomials of f belong to J; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564303).